# where can i learn to program the sqldatasource

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, sqldatasource

i am using linked severs and synonym in sql server 08

in vs08 webpage when i connect the sqldatasource to the db it doesnot show the linked server or the synonyms!! (i don't know why it doesnot show the linked severs).

so i write queries manually for the sql datasource like

```
select * from synonymname;
```

i would like to use the facilities given by sqldatasource when it binds to controls like like view etc.

from where can i learn how to program the sqldatasource and write queries for insert delete update such that when biding to any grid, it works perfectly offering all the features like paging deleting insert updating etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just setup the sql data source as one would for accessing and performing operations on a normal table, and bind to grid view

now

click on the sql data source in design view and view its properties there is the select query, delete query etc see how they are written and then use a sqldatasource but there write similar queries to access ur linkserver... and then bind to grid view,

it will work as if its working with local database

Answer (score 2):

Linked Servers and synonyms are very special features of SQL Server. Most designers don't understand them. I would abstract the linked server on server side. Write some VIEWs that encapsulate the queries to the linked server and use those views in your application.

I don't have a resource about the SqlDataSource.